How to force soft keyboard appears on default display only by ADB or Settings
I am trying to find the way to make soft keyboard appears on default display only in Android devices which support multiple displays. Currently, when the focused app on non-default display, the soft keyboard also appears on non-default display.
According to https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/multi_display/ime-support, this can be set by WindowManager#setDisplayImePolicy(). But I don't know the way to call this method.
Is there any way to force soft keyboard appears on default display only by ADB or Settings or Android/Java apps... without rooting devices? Thanks.

"But I don't know the way to call this method" -- that looks like it is only available to firmware developers. My guess is that you will need to contact the device manufacturer and ask them for assistance.

@CommonsWare  Thanks for your suggestion. I am trying to find the general way (via adb/settings/code...) for all devices. BTW, in case of Samsung manufacturer, do you know how to contact them to ask for such kind of things. I haven't asked manufacturer before. It is helpful if you can share with me. Thanks.
